# Name of anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-types

I'm describe a class

```
public class MyClass{ ... }
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass m= new MyClass(){ };
        System.out.println(m.getClass.getName);
    }
}
```

output:

```
main.Main$1
```

And what this output does mean? I describe anonymous class, hence `m` has anonymous type. I expected a `NullPointerException` be thrown.

Comment: What is `new MyClass(){ }` supposed to mean? Why the block?

Comment: @Lutz Horn: it's simply a `Foo`-example. In reality, the Topic Poster will probably inherit an interface.

Comment: Your example **does not** show any anonymous classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm excepted `NullPointerException`.

Why? Which part of the code made you expect this?

> And what this output does mean?

The anonymous class used in your class are numbered in the order in which they appear in the class. `main.Main$1` means that was the first anonymous class created.

For example, consider this example:

```
class MyClass { }

public class Demo {

    static MyClass obj = new MyClass() { 
        { 
            System.out.println("static field: " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    };

    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass() { 
        { 
            System.out.println("instance field: " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    };    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo obj4 = new Demo();

        MyClass obj3 = new MyClass() { 
            { 
                System.out.println("local variable: " + this.getClass().getName());
            }
        };    

    }
}
```

Don't worry about those blocks. Those are just instance initializer blocks in each anonymous class.

When you execute this code, you will get the following output:

```
static field: Demo$1
instance field: Demo$2
local variable: Demo$3
```

Now try moving the `static` field after the `instance` field, and see what name they get.

Comment: _Why? Which part of the code made you expect this?_ Because there is no name for anonymous classes, but i'm trying to print name of anonymous classes, hence i'm trying to print _nothing_. But i'm explained earlier that `null` is nothing.

Comment: @St.Antario It's not that there is no name of the anonymous class. Compiler internally generates name for each anoymous class when you compile your code.

Comment: Then i dont understand how can realize what does mean anonymous type? I trying to reason, that every instance of anonymous class has anonymous type.

Comment: @St.Antario What exactly is your doubt. Are you by any chance mixing the anonymous classes with generics. The question which you asked earlier?

Comment: Yes, as i understand from one of your erlied answers `CAP#1` is anonymous type, internally created by compiler. I'm trying to find the similar example from the anonymous classes because there is no name too.

Comment: @St.Antario Names for anonymous classes too are generated by compiler. But don't mixup generics with some other concept.

Comment: I'm confused. Please tell me, what does mean anonymous type, like `CAP#1`.

Comment: @St.Antario In simple words, anonymous types are the types, whose name is generated by compiler. We don't know the name before hand. Don't dig into too much details, that will confuse you.

Comment: And for no name type of `null` we have that compiler generated name for this type internally? Or it's exception to the rule.

Answer (score 3):

> And what this output does mean?

Main$1 means first anonymous class under Main.

**Note:-** `$` denotes for inner class

> I'm excepted `NullPointerException.

Why you are expecting so? Please provide few reasons for that. :)